# Cascading JS functions - How to transfer the variables from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am trying to re-create a very simple tiling calculator:

Step 1 - collects the length and width of an area and returns the area to cover with tiles.

Step 2 - collects the length and width of the tiles to determine their size.

Step 3 - divides the area by tile size and calculates how many tiles of a certain size will be required.

```
// First step is to calculate the area to tile
function surfaceArea(surfaceWidth, surfaceLength, surfaceUnit) {
    console.log( Math.ceil( surfaceWidth * surfaceLength ) + surfaceUnit );
    return Math.ceil( surfaceWidth * surfaceLength );
}

// Second step is to calculate the size of the tile
function tileArea(tileWidth, tileLength, tileUnit) {
    console.log( Math.ceil( tileWidth * tileLength ) + tileUnit );
    return Math.ceil( tileWidth * tileLength );
}

//Third step is to calculate how many tiles are required to cover the surface area
function tileAmount(surfaceArea, tileArea) {
    console.log( Math.ceil( surfaceArea * 10000 / tileArea ) );
    return Math.ceil( surfaceArea * 10000 / tileArea );
}

let surfaceWidth = prompt('Please enter the width of the surface in metres', 'For example: 5');
let surfaceLength = prompt('Please enter the length of the surface in metres', 'For example: 5');
let surfaceUnit = 'm²';
let sqm = surfaceArea(surfaceWidth, surfaceLength, surfaceUnit);

let tileWidth = prompt('Please enter the width of the tile in centimetres', 'For example: 30');
let tileLength = prompt('Please enter the length of the tile in centimetres', 'For example: 30');;
let tileUnit = 'cm²';
let tile = tileArea(tileWidth, tileLength, tileUnit);

tileAmount();
```

I am not sure how to capture the calculations in functions 1 and 2 and call them into function 3 to divide one by the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't simply

`let amount = tileAmount(sqm, tile);`

do the job?